# Can I see when a question was viewed?

Tags: support, views

I'm interested in how many additional views a question got after it was edited, an answer was posted, or some other change took place.

Is there a way to break down the total number of views over time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. This information is not tracked. Sorry.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to toss this in as a feature request along with a revision (to include the view count on the question) which could then be displayed in the posts/{id}/timeline? While historical data would be impossible to add, for future it may prove to be quite useful to the person asking the question in trying to gauge its utility (and possibly go into that mysterious "helped" metric that's on MSE for answers).

Comment: I also think this would be a useful, If I were interested in making it a feature request, should I just add the feature request tag to my question. Or should I ask a new question?

Comment: @2cents this question is more of a support one than a discussion (or feature request).  A feature request might be in order if its a reasonable one that won't get status-declined or duped (I can't find a dup... the closest I could find is [Chart: Statistics (views, votes, favorites) versus time and revisions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120779/213963) which states what Shog is stating here).