# Let's track when a question was viewed!

Tags: feature-request, views

As a followup to [Can I see when a question was viewed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288604/can-i-see-when-a-question-was-viewed) I'd like to request that question views be stored in such a way that they can be broken down over time. This would allow analysis of whether editing a post or a post receiving a new answer increased its view rate, as well as looking at views relative to other events.

[Chart: Statistics (views, votes, favorites) versus time and revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120779/chart-statistics-views-votes-favorites-versus-time-and-revisions) suggests some interesting visualizations that could be made if such statistics were available. Sadly, it is currently not possible to make such graphs because the information is not tracked.

If the amount of data is an issue, the views could be binned relative to interesting events such as edits or on a daily basis.

Comment: That sounds like a lot more data to track.  Is this feasible?

Comment: Many analytics tools do daily breakdowns. Maybe I should make it clear that the views could be binned.

Comment: The graph always looks the same.  SO: `|_______`, Reddit/Meta/HackerNews/NewsLetter: `|_||____`, Bounty: `|______|`

Comment: @HansPassant You're saying that most questions will be viewed a lot when they are first posted, or when a bounty expires, but that the rest of the graph will be uninteresting? I still think small spikes could be useful. I'm always curious whether bumping a "on hold" or negative quoted question to the front page with an substantial edit actually gets new views since the stigma of the vote count or status is a massive disincentive to view the question.

Comment: @ryanyuyu storing the count of the views on the question for each revision is "only" an additional int/revision (or the addition of about 8 characters to the body of the post). That doesn't seem like too much overhead. Per day would be a bit awkward. Per timeline event would be... probably more than revision, but not sure how much more.

Comment: Voting and viewing patterns trend together. The trend supports @Hans' suggestion.

Comment: @TravisJ No. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/792432/1927206. How many of those views come from "within" SO? Tiny amount. The votes came in two "waves". For question and answer when I asked a question on Meta(SE) (hence the Community Wiki) and there was a second wave a short time ago, when both the question and answer got an upvote. Nothing to do with when the question was asked, or edited, or answers were made. None of it :-). May be an extreme example, but correlation to views relies on assumptions which may not be valid at all, at least no valid in all cases

Comment: I would at least like to sort a search by recent views, so I know which older posts people are still viewing (and thus are worth editing).

Comment: @BillWoodger - That is a good point.