# Should there be a "famous answer" badge?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

There are no badges analogous to the popular/notable/famous question badges, which are awarded for page views. However, it seems quite possible that one of the answers was what drew the visitor to the page. Certainly, finding good answers will increase someone's chance of joining or coming back to the site.

Has there been any thought given to rewarding the answerers with a badge? Obviously there would need to be some requirements such as a positive score, though I don't think being the accepted answer would necessarily need to be a requirement.

Comment: Have fun trying to track down which answer it was, or if it was even an answer that drew the attention

Comment: @DJDavid98 That's why I said "answerers" which I'm sure is a perfectly cromulent word, despite what my spell checker wants me to think. There's no way to tell if it's an answer or question that drew the page view, which is my point.

Comment: This will just result in people going around to the highest viewed questions and posting answers to get the badge.

Comment: @Servy Yes it would. That's why "there would need to be some requirements..."

Comment: There are the [nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) et al badges already, which make a better sense as just from views.

Comment: I would like to understand why this question is worth a downvote for so many people

Comment: @Gulzar the answer I accepted below explains pretty well why this is impossible to do without a massive increase in tracking. Votes on meta questions like this are just "I like this idea" or "I don't like this idea."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This won't be possible, currently. [When a question was viewed is not tracked.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288604/can-i-see-when-a-question-was-viewed)

If I posted an answer to a question with 15k views today, the current data would also attribute those 15k existing views to my brand new answer.

For this to be at all possible, or at least fairly tracked and awarded, SE would have to *start* tracking when a question is viewed, and only views that come in *after* the answer was posted would count. Otherwise, posting an answer that gets a couple upvotes in a day to a "famous" question would easily net you the badge. Even then, we would very likely have a lot of false positives: A low-scoring answer in a list of several could get this badge despite no one scrolling down past the first couple of answers.

As a side note, the fact that the time of question views is not tracked is also what makes the "impact" calculation on your profile decently invalid for answers you've posted. If you post a qualifying answer on a frequently viewed question, your answer will inherit those views and they'll be added to your "impact score."

Comment: That makes perfect sense; of course they wouldn't want to store a timestamp for every page view. Should have thought of that myself!